# ReferenceError: listen is not defined in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, ubuntu

I have installed NodeJS on Ubuntu (14.04) and i am trying to get my first code working:

```
var http = require("http");

http.createServer(function(request,response){
    response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});
    response.write("<html>");
    response.write("<head><title>Node.JS</title></head>");
    respons.write("<body>Hello web</body>");
    respons.write("</html>");
    response.end();
}),
listen(9999);
```

I get this error:

```
/home/privateuser/nodejsweb/helloweb.js:11
listen(9999);
^
ReferenceError: listen is not defined

at Object.<anonymous> (/home/privateuser/nodejsweb/helloweb.js:11:5)
at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
at startup (node.js:119:16)
at node.js:929:3
```

During install of NodeJS i got an error during install of optional "something": 
Optional: install build tools
To compile and install native addons from npm you may also need to install build tools:
    apt-get install -y build-essential

got error:=> E: Kon het vergrendelingsbestand '/var/lib/dpkg/lock' niet openen - open (13: Toegang geweigerd)
E: Kan de beheersmap (/var/lib/dpkg/) niet vergrendelen. Heeft u beheerdersrechten?

when i used this command with sudo it tells me the last version is already installed?

Then i have tried:
auto-apt run node helloweb.js
Entering auto-apt mode: node helloweb.js
Exit the command to leave auto-apt mode.

But still gives the reference error for listen?

Please help, this is my second day with Ubuntu and my first NodeJS example and i am already stuck now:(

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var http = require("http");

http.createServer(function(request,response){
    response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});
    response.write("<html>");
    response.write("<head><title>Node.JS</title></head>");
    respons.write("<body>Hello web</body>");
    respons.write("</html>");
    response.end();
}).listen(9999);
```

`listen` is a function that needs to be called on what is returned by `createServer`

Comment: Thanks, changing the comma for a dot did the trick, but then i got a reference error for respons....2typos, changed it to response and now my first example works! Thank you!